# Highlighting parts of text document with ng2-pdf-viewer

Tags: angular

I have an application that should be able to display highlighted parts of a pdf-document. The application will be provided a certain line of text from each pdf. I want to be able to input this text-line and highlight this specific part of the pdf-document. I am currently using ng2-pdf-viewer.

I am quite new to angular and how all components interact, so I don't really get how my search()-function bellow can be connected to my acctual pdf-viewer. Right now I just get an error message saying

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pdfFindController' of undefined

since I haven't really connected the pdf-viewer to the search()-function.

In my ts file I have the following code (I have just included the relevant parts)

```
import {PdfViewerComponent} from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';

  pdfViewer: PdfViewerComponent;
  stringToSearch = 'hi';

  search() {
    this.pdfViewer.pdfFindController.executeCommand('find', {
      caseSensitive: false, findPrevious: undefined, highlightAll: true, 
phraseSearch: true, query: this.stringToSearch
    });
  }
```

In my html-file I have

```
<div *ngIf="showPreview" (click)="search()" class="search-result-preview- 
   darken">
  <div class="search-result-preview-container">
    <pdf-viewer
      [render-text]="true"
      style="display: block;"
      [src]="(staticUrl+'pdf/'+result.name)">
    </pdf-viewer>

  </div>
</div>
```

How can I connect these to make my application work as described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer#search-in-the-pdf) you have to Link the PdfViewerComponent to your component by adding it as `@ViewChild`:

```
import {PdfViewerComponent} from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';

  @ViewChild(PdfViewerComponent, {static: false}) private pdfViewer: PdfViewerComponent;
  stringToSearch = 'hi';

  search() {
    this.pdfViewer.pdfFindController.executeCommand('find', {
      caseSensitive: false, findPrevious: undefined, highlightAll: true, phraseSearch: true, query: this.stringToSearch
    });
  }
```

Comment: hi @Daniel Habenicht I'm using the same method to display pdf in angular code. will I be able to highlight multiple passages at a time with different colors. or can I get the highlighted content text value?